# Slider controllers

Tags: javascript, variables, slider

I'm trying to make an slider with two types of controllers (dots, and slide names).
I'm finding troubles trying to make this two controllers react at the same time. When clicking the dot controller number 2 an active class is add to the dot. At the same time the slide name controller number 2 should have that active class. I'm stuck :([image]

```
var sliderName = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-name");
var sliderDot = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dot");
for (var i = 0; i < sliderName.length; i++) {
   sliderName[i].addEventListener("click" , function clickBtn() {
      this.classList.toggle("slider-btn-active");
      sliderDot[i].classList.toggle("slider-btn-active");
      /*var test = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[i];
      alert(test);
      this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children.classList.toggle("slider-btn-active");*/
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the classes to toggle both when clicking the sliderName and the sliderDot?

You could create a `goToSlide` function by itself and use it for both clicks on the sliderName and the sliderDot.

```js
var sliderName = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-name");
var sliderDot = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dot");

function goToSlide(slideIndex) {
  sliderName[slideIndex].classList.toggle("slider-btn-active");
  sliderDot[slideIndex].classList.toggle("slider-btn-active");
}

for (let i = 0; i < sliderName.length; i++) {
  sliderName[i].addEventListener("click" , function () {
     goToSlide(i);
  });
  
  sliderDot[i].addEventListener("click" , function () {
     goToSlide(i);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This begs for delegation

Without seeing the rest of the HTML, here is one that syncs the two sets

```js
const sliderContainer = document.getElementById('sliderContainer'); // or whatever is the selector for the closest common container
const dots = sliderContainer.querySelectorAll(".slider-dot");
const buttons = sliderContainer.querySelectorAll(".slider-name");
sliderContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const isDot = tgt.matches(".slider-dot");
  const isName = tgt.matches(".slider-name");
  if (!isDot && !isName) return // not a dot or a button
  dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
    dot.classList.toggle("slider-btn-active", isDot ? tgt === dot : tgt === buttons[i])
  });
  buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
    button.classList.toggle("slider-btn-active", isDot ? tgt === dots[i] : tgt === button)
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-btn-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderContainer">
  <span class="slider-dot">*</span>
  <span class="slider-dot">*</span>
  <span class="slider-dot">*</span>
  <span class="slider-dot">*</span>
  <span class="slider-dot">*</span><br/>
  <span class="slider-name">*</span>
  <span class="slider-name">*</span>
  <span class="slider-name">*</span>
  <span class="slider-name">*</span>
  <span class="slider-name">*</span>
</div>
```